# Alerting Attribute Content

Tags: jquery

http://jsbin.com/uzogag/2/edit

I've attempted and searched for jQuery code that will alert "English" from the attribute selector. It's simple a newbie questions, but a good exercise. Would some kind soul lend wisdom?

**JavaScript**

```
$('p[language]').alert(this.text());
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Select elements with specific text:</h1>
    <div>
    <p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
    <p language="English">This is paragraph 2.</p>
    <p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
    <p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
    </div>
  <form>
     <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="setStyle()"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery object's do not have an `alert` method. Do this instead:

```
alert($('p[language]').attr('language'));
```

The selector `p[language]` will find the `<p>` element that has a `language` attribute.

The `attr` method returns the value of the attribute, in this case, "English". If the selector matched more than one element, this method will retrieve the value of the first match.

The `alert` method is a global function (i.e. it's a member of the `window` object).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('p[language]').click( function() {
    alert($(this).attr('language'));
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Native JavaScript method `alert` is not chainable with jQuery objects.

```
alert($('p[language]').attr('language'))
```